# Animal body size determination for abundance

Tags: zoology, morphology, community-ecology, animal-models

Does an animal being small or large determine its abundance?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! There is an [expectation](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) that question-askers show that they have done preliminary research prior to posting. There appear to be many good and free-to-read papers addressing your question, found by a simple Google Scholar search.  See -- [*Relationships between body size and abundance in ecology*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.545.8241&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (PDF)

Comment: closely related https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/24482/how-big-should-the-human-population-be-as-predicted-by-body-mass/24495#24495

Answer (score 1):

I'm sympathetic to @Dirigible that this seems like the kind of thing that should be easy to research, but I was surprised to see that there's not an answer to this already on SE.Biology. So very quickly:

**Yes, there is what is known as an "allometry" relationship between body size and abundance in which the two tend to be inversely related.**

[Here is one meta-analysis](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0065250409004012) that attempts to describe the relationship across food webs. [Here is a review article](https://www.pnas.org/content/109/39/15829) that may be easier to read describing the law in somewhat more general terms. Here is a figure from the review with plots showing the relationships in different kinds of organisms from different studies:

[image]

In some cases people talk about the population *density* in some area rather than overall abundance, as density is easier to estimate and can be thought of as a local measure of abundance. From the review you can see that there are some equations that people have derived to describe the relationship:

> For large compilations of population densities, the relationship between the average mass of a species (Msp) and its average density (Ncomp) is generally well fit by a power function ($r^2 > 80\%$), with an exponent near 0.75 so that $N_{comp} = cM^{\frac{-3}{4}}$, where c is a constant (also known as Damuth’s Rule)...